# Can I use Interaction Context in C# App?

Tags: c#, multi-touch

The Interaction Context is a new library of touch and gesture on Windows 8(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448840(v=vs.85).aspx). 
I am wondering if I can use it for a C# winform app or a WPF app.

Comment: Yes, you can use the Interaction Context for a C# WinForms app. I posted an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607234/Using-Windows-8-Interaction-Context-For-Processing) to codeproject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as you're targeting Windows 8.  Have a look through out the documentation and you'll see "Minimum supported client Windows 8 [desktop apps only]" all over it.

Here is another link you may find useful:
[Is there a way to simulate touch events in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507568/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-touch-events-in-windows-8=)

Comment: I found an example in C++. But I cannot find a way to reference the APIs in C#.

Comment: Here's a post that goes on about how they implemented some of the aspects in C#.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tabletandtouch/thread/706d8c29-657b-4073-8b5d-a1650678d342/

Comment: Hi sous, I've read those threads. It seems they are talking about how to simulate touch inputs. Interaction Context APIs are for the recognition of gestures. But Thank you.